# Need assistance in connecting my PSU fan cable

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, fan

I noticed that my PSU got really hot during gaming (to the point where it shut down my computer). I searched my PSU's model name (AXP-630P12P) and it said that the fan on the PSU was supposed to start once it got to a certain temperature. I have never in my life seen my fan move, and the warranty has expired (so I can't return it for a faulty fan).

I suspect that the fan cable might be disconnected somewhere, and am trying to figure out how to connect it to whatever it should be connected to. I tried searching, but couldn't get anywhere.

My specs are the following:
Asus P7H55/USB3 Motherboard
Nvidia GTX 550 Ti
Intel Core i3 550, 3.20Ghz
AXP-630P12P 630 watt PSU

What does the PSU's fan cable look like, and where does it go?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: PSU fans are an internal part of the unit. If it's malfunctioning, replace the PSU. For safety reasons, it is not advisable to disassemble the PSU.

Comment: Seriously? Ever heard of Google? Try Googling for your mobo model number and go get the user manual. Then read it to find out where the fan is supposed to be connected... Never mind, I did your work for you - http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P7H55USB3/#support

Comment: The issue is that it has never worked and i cant replace it yet as i want to check on all possibilies, doesnt some Psu fans got to be connected to the motherboard to work? that's about the only information i've been getting out of google.

Comment: I gave you a link to the support page for that mobo. Download the user manual in the language of your choice and read it. The manual will tell you where the fan should be plugged into on the mobo.

Answer (score 1):

Your PSU (AXP-630p12p) Fan has a 2-pin connector and is connected inside the PSU itself.

You might be able to unplug the fan from inside the PSU and connect it to a Fan Extender Cable and plug it into the Motherboard. But, if the fan isn't working, it is probably a problem with the PSU itself and not the Fan. This can also be very dangerous if you don't know what cables to unplug or how to properly wire components together.

I would recommend replacing the whole PSU.

Comment: Power supplies can be dangerous to open, even if unplugged - they often have high-capacity capacitors that can seriously hurt or even kill you if you aren't careful.

Answer (score 1):

I had one of these super silent PSUs (different) in one of the computers. The fan would turn on when the PSU got to a certain temperature. Whatever it thought it could do, it was not doing it well enough for me. It would get very hot and then the fan would start moving, but the heat roaring out vs. the air exchange was too low still.

Because the PSU fan was also a part of my total cooling (usually), I just pulled the fan that they had in there, put in a 3-pin fan, got a short fan extension, and plugged it right into one of the fan headers on the motherboard. Of course this is carefully routed out of the PSU, and even grommets would be applied as needed to keep the wire from touching the PSU case even after use and wear.

The assumption here was whenever my computers whole fan set increased in speed, the PSU fan would increase in speed also.  Because the fan was a high(er) rpm fan, and never was stopped, and was always cooling better than the original idea. By using a 3-pin fan and connecting it to my motherboard, I could monitor the speed it was going too.

The changeover was rather easy, because of the positioning of the fan in this PSU, the original wiring was to a 2-pin header. I have done many other fan replaces in PSUs just to put in a ball bearing fan for longevity, where soldering it in was required. The connection was already supplied by the motherboard, because it had a header for monitoring a PSU. Because the PSU itself did not have an ability to monitor, it was one more thing that pushed me into wanting to change it.

Ramification: It has to be connected to the motherboard header, and reconnected if I am in there cleaning or something. Because I am very careful to check things and test them again, it isn't a problem for me. Failing to use it and set it properly could very well be worse than what they are doing. I have had separate fans controlled by both Q-Fan (motherboards own) and Speedfan. But speedfan for example could fail, as it is totally software based.  Overall I tried to think of every contingency. All of my modifications have worked for at least five years.

Disclaimer: You have to be careful with the high voltage capacitors in there.

This is what I did. I am not suggesting that it is the correct move for anyone else. I still think replacing it is probably the best idea. If I could not have fixed mine, I do not think I would have used it the way they had it. They may have had it all worked out, but the method was not for me.